# C++ storing cin input and skipping others

Tags: c++, string, input, cin

I'm having trouble skipping certain inputs.

```
int main(){
  string input;
  string lastName;
  string firstName;
  int age;
  int streetNum;
  string streetName;
  string town;
  string zipCode;
  float balance;
```

later on

```
Update(lastName, firstName, age, streetNum, streetName, town, zipCode, balance);
}
```

The idea is, if the user enters nothing (just hits enter) the value should stay the same and move to the next input.

```
void Update(string &lastname, string &firstname, int &age, int &streetnum, string &streetname, string &town, string &zipcode, float &balance){
  cout << "Update the following, enter nothing to leave the same: " << endl;
  string input;
  size_t sz;

  cout << "Last name: ";
  cin >> input;
  if (!input.empty()) { lastname = input; }

  cout << "First name: ";
  cin >> input;
  if (!input.empty()) { firstname = input; }

  cout << "Age: ";
  cin >> input;
  if (!input.empty()) { age = stoi(input, &sz); }

  cout << "Street number: ";
  cin >> input;
  if (!input.empty()) { streetnum = stoi(input, &sz); }

  cout << "Street name: ";
  cin >> input;
  if (!input.empty()) { streetname = stoi(input); }

  cout << "Town name:";
  cin >> input;
  if (!input.empty()) { town = input; }

  cout << "ZipCode: ";
  cin >> input;
  if (!input.empty()) { zipcode = input; }

  cout << "Balance: ";
  cin >> input;
  if (!input.empty()) { balance = stof(input); }

}
```

All my attempts have failed to skip the input if the user only hits enter.

Comment: I sense a need for `std::getline`.

Comment: Just make sure you don't try to mix `std::getline` and `>>` input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `cin` for your code is:

- it [ignores the blanks](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/skipws/), and newline (enter) is a blank
- it uses the blanks as separator of value so "Baker street" would be read as two strings, the second being taken for the town.

Consider use of [`getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/?kw=getline) into a string (and eventually stringstream to parse further the result received):

```
   getline (cin, input);    // instead of cin>>input;
```

*By the way, streetname isn't an integer, is it ? ;-)*